# How to report sub-resource-integrity failure back to service

Tags: javascript, security

Sub-resource integrity is a great way to make sure CDN has not been compromised. However, I could not find any way to handle the failure and report it back to the service.

AKA: as the developer of the website I would like to know when integrity check failed for a specific file.

Comment: hold on, `Content-Security-Policy` allows browser to report back for violation with its [`report-uri`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri) (or the newer one, [`report-to`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to)) directive.. so how did you do your `sub-resource-integrity`..?

Comment: @BagusTesa I tried several combinations of CSP rules with no success.  Could you provide an example?